# Blob Image unable to covert in to image format?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, stream, blob

Unable to retrive the blob image from mysql database using below code in mvc4 with entityframework6

```
        byte[] photo = entity.collections.Where(p => p.CustomerID == CustomerID).Select(img => img.Money_Receipt_Photo).FirstOrDefault();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(photo);
        ms.Write(photo, 0, photo.Length);
        System.Drawing.ImageConverter converter = new System.Drawing.ImageConverter();
        System.Drawing.Image returnImage = (Image)converter.ConvertFrom(ms);
        return returnImage;
```

error: ImageConverter cannot convert from System.IO.MemoryStream.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are receiving the stream of bytes from the blob.
Try this code :

```
public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
{
  // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
  byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, 
    imageBytes.Length);

  // Convert byte[] to Image
  ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
  Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
  return image;
}
```

Comment: i have already tried this is my <img src="@Url.Action("GetPhoto","Home", new { CustomerID = item.CustomerID })" /> view code how to get base64string as paramter? i am getting image as bytes in here byte[] photo = entity.collections.Where(p => p.CustomerID == CustomerID).Select(img => img.Money_Receipt_Photo).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: when i want to get the bytes of image without customerid directly form view to controller by passing Money_Receipt_Photo as parameter above method is not fired

Comment: my entity public byte[] Money_Receipt_Photo { get; set; } than how it support this   byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);?